# Confusion regarding Boolean Algebra Simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to solve a simple boolean algebra equation, but am not quite sure how the answer is achieved. The question is  to simplify (\$x'y' + xy + x'y\$). I have got the following steps:

\$x'(y+y') + xy\$   is Adjacency rule, then my final answer is \$x'+xy\$. But the solution set shows the answer to be \$x'+y\$. Why so?

Comment: If it's not x' then it must x, hence x is redundant in the second term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$ x′y′ + xy + x′y\$

\$= x'y' + y(x + x')\$

\$= x'y' + y\$

\$= x' + y\$